# Using a derived function from an object inside a list object

Tags: c++, list, inheritance, polymorphism, derived

I have two classes, one of which inherits the other:

```
class baseClass
{
public:
    virtual void show();
};

void baseClass::show(){cout << "Base class" << endl;}


class derivedClass
{
public:
    void show();
};

void derivedClass::show(){cout << "Derived class" << endl;}
```

If I make a derivedClass object and called the show function, it correctly prints "Derived class". If I do the following:

```
derivedClass b;
baseClass* b;
b=&d;
b->show();
```

It again correctly prints out "Derived class".
However, if I make a list like so:

```
list<baseClass> t;
list<baseClass>::iterator it;
baseClass b;
derivedClass d;
t.push_back(b);
t.push_back(d);
```

And try to call show on each item:

```
it = t.begin();
it->show();
it++;
it->show();
```

The output for both b and d is "Base class".
My question is: why is it only using the baseClass version of show(), and how can I make it properly use the derived version for objects of derivedClass in the list?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the method `show()` as `virtual` to make polymorphism work:

```
class baseClass
{
public:
    virtual void show();
};

void baseClass::show(){cout << "Base class" << endl;}


class derivedClass : public baseClass
{
public:
    virtual void show();
};

void derivedClass::show(){cout << "Derived class" << endl;}
```

You were also missing `class derivedClass : public baseClass`.

And the final problem. You need to use pointers.

```
list<baseClass*> t;
list<baseClass*>::iterator it;
baseClass b;
derivedClass d;
t.push_back(&b);
t.push_back(&d);
```

and change to this:

```
it = t.begin();
(*it)->show();
it++;
(*it)->show();
```

Comment: My bad, that was a mistake in the question (which I have editted), show() was virtual in the baseClass. I have tried making show() virtual in the derivedClass as you said, but it is still not calling the correct function.

Comment: I'm getting the same result you're getting. It has something to do with the iterator. Gimme a sec to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a bundle, the (*it) was the part I kept getting stuck on (tried *it and *(it) yesterday too >.<) Works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

> It again correctly prints out "Derived class". However, if I make a list like so:

No. It cannot print "Derived class". In fact, this line :

```
b=&d;
```

will give [compilation error](http://ideone.com/X7MmH), since `b` is not a polymorphic base of `d`.

Declare `show` as `virtual`, in base class:

```
virtual void show();
```

Then that will compile.

However, even after making `show` virtual, pushing object of derived class, to the list will cause **object slicing** because the list can contain only base  class objects; that means, the list will get the sub-object of the derived class object. It's because you've declare the list as:

```
list<baseClass> t;
```

which is not correct.

Declare it as:

```
list<baseClass*> t;
```

and push `pointer` to object to this, like this:

```
derivedClass d;
derivedClass *pd = new derivedClass;
baseClass b;

t.push_back(&d);
t.push_back(pd); //note there is no `&`
t.push_back(&b);

//use t

//must delete pd
delete pd;
```

--

Just make a note that if you want to delete the objects of derived class, using the pointer of type base class, something like this:

```
baseClass *bptr = new derivedClass();
delete bptr;
```

then you've to define the destructor of `baseClass` as virtual, otherwise the delete statement above will invoke undefined behavior.

So do this:

```
class  baseClass:
{
  //...
  virtual ~baseClass();
};
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "insert pointer to object to this"?
Also, if i try list<baseClass*> t;
  list<baseClass*>::iterator it;
         t.push_back(&b);
  t.push_back(&d);
Then     it->show();  comes up with an error (expression must have pointer to class type)

Comment: @Alexdander: Edited the post. See now.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help, used your replies and Mysticial's together and it worked like a charm =)